# Why does the find command have -regex when there is grep?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep, find

Is there any good reason to use `find -regex REGEX` when `find | grep REGEX` is faster in any scenario, even with a small number of files to search?

If not, then why does the `-regex` option even exist?
When it also makes confusion because the regex syntax is different from the other utilities (grep, sed, awk) and in other to change it, you have to specify the tedious option `-regextype TYPE`

At least in sed and grep, it is enough to specify `-E` to use extended regular expressions instead of basic.

Comment: If the action on find is `-exec some program`, then grep isn't much help.

Comment: Notice that `-regex` is a GNU extension; POSIX `find` doesn't have it. It has been in GNU `find` forever, though – it's mentioned in [release notes](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/NEWS) from 1993 as already existing.

Comment: Here's a quote I like: `find's business is evaluating expressions -- not locating files. Yes, find certainly locates files; but that's really just a side effect.` (saw it in this excellent Q&A regarding find: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has it because you can combine it with other tests, possibly with complex boolean conditions. This would not be feasible just by piping. For example:

```
find -type f -regex 'regex1' -o -type d -regex 'regex2'
```

This uses a different regular expression for files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

`find | grep REGEX` might be faster, but it's less flexible. When using `find -regex`, you can continue with more find options, e.g. `-exec`, which might be problematic with `grep`.